# Outlook365 Add-In Event on Change Attendee Action

Tags: javascript, azure, outlook, office365, outlook-addin

I am working on to creating Outlook ADD-In for Outlook365 cloud account.
I want to capture event on  attendees change i.e rather than manually clicking on Add-In icon for every change, if someones Add or remove some attendee from calendar invite, the event can be captured and some java script function can be called in my Add-In app.

Comment: Could you describe more clearly your problem, with a [MCVE] for example.

Comment: I assume you want to capture the event using MS Graph API, however there are not a API for capture the event. If so, I think you can modify the tag `microsoft-graph` by `outlook add-in`

Answer (score 0):

In case your add-in is active and attendees are changed in appointment window, you can get events when attendees are changed. requirement set 1.7 for Outlook 2016 was made GA during IGNITE.

You need to handle RecipientsChanged events.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/office/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/outlook-requirement-set-1.7?view=office-js

You can also refer to the following youtube video for an example
https://youtu.be/xbUcGlcnfxQ

In case you want without add-in being active, you need to use graph API web-hooks to get notified of the change.